# Node.js parser for link headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-api, link-header

I'm using the Github API, which uses [Link Headers, as defined here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/9707-link-header.html), for pagination.

Currently I'm just extracting 'next' URLs using some string manipulation but I was wondering if there was a proper module for this purpose (I haven't been able to find anything in 'npm search').

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote https://github.com/wombleton/link-headers a while back — it has a terrible API, was written for a different spec, and it's not a module, but it's something. I'll see if I can turn it into a module and unsuck its API in the near future.

Comment: @wombleton That would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: [backbone-pageable](https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable/blob/master/lib/backbone-pageable.js) has a `parseLinks` function, which is used for parsing Github API Link headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this: https://npmjs.org/package/parse-links

It looks a bit fragile, to my mind, but it looks like it will do very basic parsing.